# Possible cause of this ice formation in freezer in Whirlpool refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

Model: Whirlpool WRT318FZDB02

About 6 years old.

Please see the pics, can you gauge the possible cause of the ice formation (in the top right of the freezer?). No ice on the coils.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the automatic defrost might not be working